# Headphones not working on Lubuntu 14.10

Tags: lubuntu, headphones

I just downloaded Lubuntu 14.10 and installed it, everything is fine except my headphones are not working at all.

I am using Asus X550CA Laptop and internal speaker works well but when I plug in headphones in my 3.5mm audio jack, I just don't hear anything. When I unplug them, sound resumes coming out from Laptop's speakers. And yes, headphones are working on windows and Fedora.

Comment: have you tried to go to the sound setting and setting the output to headphones

Comment: Also make sure headphones were not muted.

Comment: Open a terminal and type in alsamixer.
There make sure that headphones are unmuted.

Comment: Take a look on [this article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems).

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite a while since you asked, but I was having the same problem with an iMac and here's what I did: 
I added the following line: `options snd-hda-intel model=imac27_122` to the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. Notice how I appended my mac's model to the end of the line. Perhaps you could try it, only changing your model.